# scheme: resuming a loop after a condition has been signaled

Tags: conditional-statements, scheme, restart, mit-scheme

This program is using Scheme conditions and restarts to execute a procedure 10 times in a loop, and return the number of times the procedure did succeed.
Here the procedure throws an error each times n is a multiple of 3.
For some reason, the first error (n=3) is caught but the loop fails to resume with n=4:

```
(define (handle! thunk)
  (bind-condition-handler
   '() (lambda (condition)
         (display "resuming...")
         (invoke-restart (find-restart 'next)))
   thunk))

(let loop((n 1) (count 0))
  (display n)(display #\,)
  (if (> n 10) count
      (handle!
       (call/cc
        (lambda (cc)
          (with-restart
           'next "restart here"
           (lambda ()
             (cc (loop (1+ n) count)))
           #f
           (lambda ()
             (if (= 0 (modulo n 3))
                 (error n "is multiple of 3!")
                 (loop (1+ n) (1+ count))))))))))
```

I failed to find examples of conditions and restarts beyond the ones at [the MIT Scheme Reference](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/scheme_17.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to move down the call/cc to the loop argument 'count' which is affected by the condition:

```
(let loop((n 1) (count 0))
  (display n)(display #\,)
  (if (> n 10) count
      (handle!
       (lambda()
         (loop (1+ n)
               (call/cc
                (lambda (cc)
                  (with-restart
                   'next "restart here"
                   (lambda ()
                     (cc count))
                   #f
                   (lambda ()
                     (if (= 0 (modulo n 3))
                         (error n "is multiple of 3!"))
                     (1+ count))))))))))
```

Runs correctly:

```
1 ]=> 1,2,3,resuming...4,5,6,resuming...7,8,9,resuming...10,11,
;Value: 7
```